# Is there a way to play a game with some elements from "Empire of the Smoky Skies" scenario?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

The "Empire of the Smoky Skies" scenario has a unique tech-tree (complete with unique units and buildings), unique social policies, unique leaders and unique victory conditions, as well as forced game speed and forced starting era.

**Is there a way to play a game which uses only some of these elements?** For instance, can I play it starting from an earlier era, with a different game pacing, and with standard social policies, but with the same tech-tree, leaders and victory conditions? Or play it with standard leaders, but all the rest remaining the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be no direct way of doing it, but I'm starting to see some mods which enable some of the scenario's features in a standard game:

- Luboric resource: [civfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=469942) [workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=83975297)
- Luboric and the landship-category units, via a tech-tree branch: [civfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=470128) [workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=84440031)

Please update this post if additional scenario-inspired mods come out.